# Is there a tool to check and manage file permissions?

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, file-permissions

I developed a set of rules for file and directory owner and permissions for our company server. E.g.:

```
Projects/: permission 750, owner root, group internal
Projects/* (directories): permission 2770, group internal
Projects/*/* (files): permission 644, group internal
Projects/*/* (directories): permission 2770, group internal
Office/: permission 2770, owner root, group internal
...
```

I started to write a script for checking these rules. But this became really uncomfortable. An option for automatic correction would be also nice. I already discovered systemd-tmpfiles which does a similar job but (imho) lacks of reporting feature. I don't know if it will support the wildcards, too. Defining some exclusions rules would also be nice.

Does someone know if there's maybe a solution for that? I already searched for linux file system permission services, but the results were really misleading.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic. But every configuration management tool is able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`mtree`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree).

> The utility mtree compares the file hierarchy rooted in the current directory against a specification read from the standard input.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for that hint. Despite that there seems to be really less documentation I checked some features. The following guide helped me a lot: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/small-guide-on-using-mtree.61113/ But I think mtree does not cover my use case of checking all directories (and files) recursively. E.g.: find -type d -not \( -perm 2770 -and -group office \). This would also check all sub-directories.